# Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4623634 0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
import csv
with open ("Filename1.txt") as f:
   dict1 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:

       a, b, v = row
       dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

   #for key in dict1:
      #print(key[0])
      #print(key[1])
      #print(d[key][0]])

with open ("Filename2.txt") as f:
   dict2 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:

       a, b, v = row
       dict2.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

   #for key in dict2:
       #print(key[0])

    count = 0
    for key1 in dict1:
       for key2 in dict2:
          if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and abs(float(key1[1])) - (float(key2[1])) < 10000:
           count += 1
```

Previously I was getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/MainDict.py", line 28, in <module>
if key1[0] == key2[0] and abs(key1[1] - key2[1]) < 10000:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

So of course I tried turning those strings into integers. However I then got this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/MainDict.py", line 28, in <module>
 if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and abs((int(key1[1])) - (int(key2[1]))) < 10000:
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1002569 1'
```

Then I tried using float and now I get this error, which is where I am stuck now:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/MainDict.py", line 28, in <module>
 if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and abs(float(key1[1])) - (float(key2[1])) < 10000:
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2486997 2'
```

Here are examples of what my input files consist of:

Filename1

```
1   11383002    8 1.16E-05
1   159962368   1.17E-05
2   133623587   1.26E-05
2   1002569 1   3.30E-06
3   168940139   1.40E-05
3   49736942    1.43E-05
```

Filename2

```
10  11383002    8 1.16E-05
5   159962368   1.17E-05
7   133623587   1.26E-05
9   1002569 1   3.30E-06
8   168940139   1.40E-05
1   49736942    1.43E-05
```

Now my question is, why am I getting this error. Is there something in the code specifically? Or is there something wrong with my text files. What suggestions do you having on fixing this problem and how can I alter my code (if that's the case) to do so?

Comment: What number do you think "1002569 1" should be?

Comment: `1002569 1` is not a valid float or integer number actually its not a valid number since it contains space! so what you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what number `1002569 1` should be, but maybe use `split(" ")[0]` to get just the first part of it and convert that into an `int`?

```
if ... and abs(float(key1[1].split(" ")[0])) - (float(key2[1].split(" ")[0])) < 10000:
```

This will also work if there is no space (like in the other rows).

Comment: You're welcome! Out of curiosity, @JimJones, where does the extra space come from in your input?

Comment: Well I am not entirely sure. If you look at the example of one of my files above, with the three columns i created a dictionary. I used the first two columns as my key and the third as my value. So when python iterated over my files, i dont know if it assumed that "2351452 1" (one of my keys) was a single number. And with that space in there it obviously isent so i got the error. But by removing the space like you suggested, python could then read them as two individual numbers and it worked haha @adrianus